# Can the nuspec file node take any kind of variable?

Tags: nuget

I have a nuspec files node that looks like this:

```
<files>
   <file src="bin\Release\MyProject.dll" target="lib\MyProject.dll" />
</files>
```

I run my nuspec packing in a post compile step.  And it works great from Visual Studio.

But TFS does not build "normal"  It puts all the libraries and sources in a "Binaries" folder.

Is there a way I could put a variable in the `<file>` node to point to the Binaries folder when doing a TFS build and leave it normal when building in a Visual Studio Build?

I would rather not have to have two nuspec files (one for TFS and one for visual studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by making a package folder in the project for which i wanted to make a Nuget package.

There I make all the folders and unchanging files in there.

I added a post build step in the project that copies the files that just have been built into the package folder and run Nuget.exe

So it goes:

Build Project
Copy output back into Package\Lib of project
Run Nuget.exe with nuspec file in package folder
Copy result to output folder next to the rest of the output.

Nuget.exe has to be either in a fixed folder on your system and the buildserver (dirty solution) or included in your build (less dirty).

Comment: Would you be willing to share your post build script?  (So I could adapt it to my paths?)

Comment: Xcopy.exe /Y  "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)\Package\Lib" 

cd "$(ProjectDir)Package"

"$(TargetDir)..\Buildscripts\Nuget.exe" pack MyPackage.nuspec

xcopy /Y  *.nupkg "$(TargetDir)" 

Only thing you have to take care of to use this, is where to check the nuget.exe. I made a buildscripts folder on the top level of my development tree.

Comment: Turns out that Nuget has a "BasePath" option.  If you pass that in then you can get the nuspec to take different paths.  (Also, NuGet has a option that will take a .csproj file)

Comment: You're right, but I had to copy/paste this block of text to 24 projects and I didn't want to change too much in every project...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to do this with command-line

In your pre-build event command line
If the nuget spec doesn't exist, then create it and wait 5 seconds

```
cd "$(TargetDir)..\..\"
if exist $(TargetDir)..\..\*.nuspec (goto dontcreatespec) ELSE (goto createspec)
:createspec
nuget spec -f
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
:dontcreatespec
```

In your post-build event command line
Wait for 5 seconds, find and replace the template strings with your own using fart and then copy to another directory

```
cd "$(TargetDir)..\..\"
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul
set find1="Summary of changes made in this release of the package."
set replace1="summary test"
set find2="http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE"
set replace2="http://test.com"
set find3="Tag1 Tag2"
set replace3="testtag"
set find4="http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE"
set replace4="http://test.com"
set find5="http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE"
set replace5="http://test.com"
fart -i "$(TargetDir)..\..\*.nuspec" %find1% %replace1%
fart -i "$(TargetDir)..\..\*.nuspec" %find2% %replace2%
fart -i "$(TargetDir)..\..\*.nuspec" %find3% %replace3%
fart -i "$(TargetDir)..\..\*.nuspec" %find4% %replace4%
fart -i "$(TargetDir)..\..\*.nuspec" %find5% %replace5%
nuget pack $(ProjectPath)
xcopy *.nupkg "$(TargetDir)..\..\..\localpackages" /s /d /y
```

You will need Nuget.exe and fart.exe

https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases

http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/

Put them in a Path Environment variable